# Replace 10+ years to 10 in R

Tags: r

I have a column name having employment length as "10+ years"

How to replace column values having 10+ years to 10 in R ?

Comment: `sub("10+ years", "10", df$col, fixed=TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is more generalizable to any of the columns in your dataframe if it matches the pattern of **"+ years"** and replaces that section with an empty string.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create dataframe with 2 columns
df <- tibble(
  "10+ years" = c(0, 2, 4, 5),
  "better_named_column" = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
)

# column names before
names(df)
#> [1] "10+ years"           "better_named_column"

# check that replacing "+ years" with empty string looks as expected
gsub("\\+ years", "", names(df))
#> [1] "10"                  "better_named_column"

# apply to actual dataframe
names(df) <- gsub("\\+ years", "", names(df))

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>    `10` better_named_column
#>   <dbl>               <dbl>
#> 1     0                   2
#> 2     2                   3
#> 3     4                   4
#> 4     5                   5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`, you can do:

```r
names(df) <- str_replace_all(names(df), "10\\+ years", "10")
```

## Data

```r
#dput(df)
structure(list(`10+ years` = c(0, 2, 4, 5), b = c(2, 3, 4, 5), 
    `10+ years` = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```